# Building a Python implementation of min heap

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, data-structures, heap

What is wrong with the below code to buld a min heap? The bubble_up method doesn't work it gets an index out of range error.

```
 def __init__(self):
    self.heap = []
    self.heap_size = 0

 def bubble_up(self, i):
    print(self.heap)
    while i // 2 > 0:
        if self.heap[i] < self.heap[i // 2]:
            tmp = self.heap[i // 2 - 1]
            self.heap[i] = self.heap[i // 2]
            self.heap[i // 2] = tmp
        print(self.heap)
        i = i // 2


def insert(self, data):
    self.heap.append(data)
    self.heap_size = self.heap_size + 1
    self.bubble_up(self.heap_size)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    min_heap = MinHeap()
    min_heap.insert(5)
    min_heap.insert(4)
    min_heap.insert(3)
    min_heap.insert(2)
    min_heap.insert(6)
```

Comment: What does your debugging say is happening?

Comment: Might I inquire as to what's wrong with the [heap that comes with python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html)?

Comment: Index error and I'm attempting to build my own nothing's wrong with pythons...

Comment: Your debugging isn't telling you that you have an index error, your program is telling you that. Debugging is the act of ascertaining why a program is doing what it is doing (or at least what is happening while it is running).  Writing a program and then asking SO to debug for you will not happen.  Writing a program, debugging it and asking for help with the debug output/information has a chance of happening.

Comment: It's something wrong with my indexing methods that I'm failing to see. I fail to see what further debugging I could do past looking at my indexing methods which I have already done and still don't user stand the error or why it's happening

Answer (score 2):

```
def insert(self, data):
    self.heap.append(data)
    self.heap_size = self.heap_size + 1
    self.bubble_up(self.heap_size)
```

You append your data, increase `heap_size` and then call your `bubble_up` with the new (increased) heap size.

In there, you check:

```
 if self.heap[i] < self.heap[i // 2]:
```

where `i` is the heap size. You cannot do that, if you have `3` elements in your heap, you cannot access `heap[3]`. It won't exist, your only valid indexes are `0, 1, 2`.

Possible fix (untested): call `bubble_up` with `heap_size - 1`.

Note that the code in your `if` doesn't really look right:

```
tmp = self.heap[i // 2 - 1]        # why -1 here? shouldn't this be heap[i]?
self.heap[i] = self.heap[i // 2]   # shouldn't this be the other way around? why no -1 here?
self.heap[i // 2] = tmp            # why no -1 here? shouldn't this be heap[i]?
```

Also, you can put `i // 2` in this conditional and break out of the loop if the condition is false.

Comment: Or do bubble_up before increasing the heap size, and as for swapping use the tuple swapping `self.heap[i], self.heap[i // 2] = self.heap[i // 2], self.heap[i]`. This way, no messy temporaries lying around

Answer (score 0):

The current answer posted accurately portrays why you're getting an outofbounds error, but if you just call `bubble_up()` with `heap_size-1`, it will not maintain the heap correctly. Note the following part of your code in `bubble_up()`:

```
while i // 2 > 0:
```

Your current while loop statement will not compare immediate childs of the root of the heap to the root. Let's say you insert `3` then `1`. When you insert `1`, `bubble_up()` will not correctly swap the inserted 1 with 3 because it won't run the swap routine within your while statement due to `i//2 == 0` since `i == 1` which is the position `1` was inserted into. I'd switch this block to the following:

```
while i > 0:
    parent = i // 2
    <put your comparison & swap method here>
    i = parent
```